# Cant add firebase to android app

Tags: android, firebase

I want to add firebase to my app for push notifications. I have followed the firebase docs and have done this:

root/app/build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

root/build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

I have also added the google-services.json in `root/app` dir.
On trying to sync the project, there is an error :

> Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2

I dont understand why this error is present. How can I resolve it?

Comment: what's the minimum sdk for your app? It should be at least 8.

Comment: Also make sure you are using Android Studio 1.5 or higher.

Comment: Yup everything is up to date

Comment: You seem to be doing fine there, get google play services from your sdk manager if you haven't already done that.

Comment: I have done that too.

Comment: try to use ver 9.0.0 ,  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'

Comment: That too failed to resolve.

Comment: How about Internet connection? do you have Internet to download such dependency

Comment: Yes internet is available

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to Tools->Android->SDK Manager.
   [image: Android Studio settings]
2. In SDK Tools tab update 'Google Play services' and 'Google Repository' to minimum 30 and 28 respectively.
3. Sync project with Gradle files.

Comment: Thanks! Checking Google Play Services and Google Repository to the latest version fixed it. I wonder why Google doesn't mention this in their documentation...

Answer (score 5):

Update following SDK tools packages from SDK manager will solve your problem

See [Video](https://youtu.be/kWF1L9M9qso) How To Fix

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**update to *9.0.2* it will resolve all the problems.**

Also update **Google Repository** and **Google Play Services**.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your sdk manager to make sure the extras are up-to-date. The google services and google repository more importantly.

Answer (score 0):

First Use this in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}
```

Then Use packaganiing option

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

Here the Guidance for setup Firebase in your project [HERE](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/setup.html)

Comment: These are deprecated. Please follow the new guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Android->SDK Manager.

In SDK Tools tab update 'Google Play services' and 'Google Repository' to minimum 30 and 28 respectively.

Sync project with Gradle files.